# what is the use of the non-zero address value of the comment section?

Tags: cross-compiling, executable, elf

We're struggling to reproduce a .elf file identical to a reference. We are almost there and the files are identical but for the address of the comment section (the rest is 100% identical binary-wise).

A dump of one of the .elf files using `readelf -e` is as follows (the target is powerpc, but I don't think it's really important):

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, big endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           PowerPC
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x1800f88
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          1367724 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         5
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         20
  Section header string table index: 19

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        018000f4 0000f4 000011 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .hash             HASH            01800108 000108 000248 04   A  3   0  4
  [ 3] .dynsym           DYNSYM          01800350 000350 0004d0 10   A  4   1  4
  [ 4] .dynstr           STRTAB          01800820 000820 000473 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 5] .rela.plt         RELA            01800c94 000c94 0002dc 0c   A  3  16  4
  [ 6] .rela.sbss        RELA            01800f70 000f70 000018 0c   A  3  15  4
  [ 7] .text             PROGBITS        01800f88 000f88 0e4f78 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 8] .rodata           PROGBITS        018e5f00 0e5f00 064708 00   A  0   0  8
  [ 9] .sdata2           PROGBITS        0194a608 14a608 000000 00   A  0   0  4
  [10] .data             PROGBITS        0198a608 14a608 000b5c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [11] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         0198b164 14b164 000090 08  WA  4   0  4
  [12] .got2             PROGBITS        0198b1f4 14b1f4 000024 00  WA  0   0  1
  [13] .got              PROGBITS        0198b218 14b218 000010 04  WA  0   0  4
  [14] .sdata            PROGBITS        0198b228 14b228 001814 00  WA  0   0  8
  [15] .sbss             NOBITS          0198ca40 14ca40 00064c 00  WA  0   0  8
  [16] .plt              NOBITS          0198d08c 14ca40 000324 00 WAX  0   0  4
  [17] .bss              NOBITS          0198d3b0 14ca40 223920 00  WA  0   0 16
  [18] .comment          PROGBITS        0026a8bd 14ca40 0013cb 00      0   0  1
  [19] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 14de0b 00009e 00      0   0  1
```

The sections where address is `0` makes sense: those aren't mapped when loading the program. And the other `0x18xxxxx` values are specified by the linker specification file.

But why is there a non-zero address for the comment section (which contains details such as compiler version and execution platform), which part of the chain uses it (debugger?), and how the linker does decide where to put it ?

The linker script doesn't even mention this `.comment` section:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-powerpc", "elf32-powerpc",
"elf32-powerpc")
OUTPUT_ARCH(powerpc)
ENTRY(_start)
SEARCH_DIR(/opt/gnu/powerpc-wrs-vxworks/lib);
/* Do we need any of these for elf?
__DYNAMIC = 0;    */
PROVIDE (__stack = 0);
SECTIONS
{
/* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
. = 0x01800000 + SIZEOF_HEADERS;
.interp   : { *(.interp) }
.hash         : { *(.hash)      }
.dynsym   : { *(.dynsym)        }
.dynstr   : { *(.dynstr)        }
.gnu.version   : { *(.gnu.version)      }
.gnu.version_d   : { *(.gnu.version_d)  }
.gnu.version_r   : { *(.gnu.version_r)  }
.rela.text     :
{ *(.rela.text) *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.t*) }
.rela.data     :
{ *(.rela.data) *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.d*) }
.rela.rodata   :
{ *(.rela.rodata) *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.r*) }
.rela.got     : { *(.rela.got)  }
.rela.got1    : { *(.rela.got1) }
.rela.got2    : { *(.rela.got2) }
.rela.ctors   : { *(.rela.ctors)    }
.rela.dtors   : { *(.rela.dtors)    }
.rela.init    : { *(.rela.init) }
.rela.fini    : { *(.rela.fini) }
.rela.bss     : { *(.rela.bss)  }
.rela.plt     : { *(.rela.plt)  }
.rela.sdata   : { *(.rela.sdata)    }
.rela.sbss    : { *(.rela.sbss) }
.rela.sdata2      : { *(.rela.sdata2)   }
.rela.sbss2   : { *(.rela.sbss2)    }
.text      :
{
*(.text)
/* .gnu.warning sections are handled specially by elf32.em.  */
*(.gnu.warning)
*(.gnu.linkonce.t*)
} =0
.init         : { *(.init)      } =0
.fini         : { *(.fini)      } =0
.rodata   : { *(.rodata) *(.gnu.linkonce.r*) }
.rodata1      : { *(.rodata1) }
_etext = .;
PROVIDE (etext = .);
.sdata2   : { *(.sdata2) }
.sbss2   : { *(.sbss2) }
/* Adjust the address for the data segment.  We want to adjust up to
the same address within the page on the next page up.  It would
be more correct to do this:
. = ALIGN(0x40000) + (ALIGN(8) & (0x40000 - 1));
The current expression does not correctly handle the case of a
text segment ending precisely at the end of a page; it causes the
data segment to skip a page.  The above expression does not have
this problem, but it will currently (2/95) cause BFD to allocate
a single segment, combining both text and data, for this case.
This will prevent the text segment from being shared among
multiple executions of the program; I think that is more
important than losing a page of the virtual address space (note
that no actual memory is lost; the page which is skipped can not
be referenced).  */
. =  ALIGN(8) + 0x40000;
.data    :
{
*(.data)
*(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
CONSTRUCTORS
}
.data1   : { *(.data1) }
.got1         : { *(.got1) }
.dynamic      : { *(.dynamic) }
/* Put .ctors and .dtors next to the .got2 section, so that the pointers
get relocated with -mrelocatable. Also put in the .fixup pointers.
The current compiler no longer needs this, but keep it around for 2.7.2  */
PROVIDE (_GOT2_START_ = .);
.got2         :  { *(.got2) }
PROVIDE (__CTOR_LIST__ = .);
.ctors    : { *(.ctors) }
PROVIDE (__CTOR_END__ = .);
PROVIDE (__DTOR_LIST__ = .);
.dtors    : { *(.dtors) }
PROVIDE (__DTOR_END__ = .);
PROVIDE (_FIXUP_START_ = .);
.fixup    : { *(.fixup) }
PROVIDE (_FIXUP_END_ = .);
PROVIDE (_GOT2_END_ = .);
PROVIDE (_GOT_START_ = .);
.got          : { *(.got) }
.got.plt      : { *(.got.plt) }
PROVIDE (_GOT_END_ = .);
/* We want the small data sections together, so single-instruction offsets
can access them all, and initialized data all before uninitialized, so
we can shorten the on-disk segment size.  */
.sdata    : { *(.sdata) }
_edata  =  .;
PROVIDE (edata = .);
.sbss      :
{
PROVIDE (__sbss_start = .);
*(.sbss)
*(.scommon)
*(.dynsbss)
PROVIDE (__sbss_end = .);
}
.plt   : { *(.plt) }
.bss       :
{
PROVIDE (__bss_start = .);
*(.dynbss)
*(.bss)
*(COMMON)
}
_end = . ;
PROVIDE (end = .);
/* These are needed for ELF backends which have not yet been
converted to the new style linker.  */
.stab 0 : { *(.stab) }
.stabstr 0 : { *(.stabstr) }
/* DWARF debug sections.
Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
/* DWARF 1 */
.debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
.line           0 : { *(.line) }
/* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
.debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
.debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
/* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
.debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
.debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
/* DWARF 2 */
.debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info) }
.debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
.debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
.debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
.debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
.debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
.debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
/* SGI/MIPS DWARF 2 extensions */
.debug_weaknames 0 : { *(.debug_weaknames) }
.debug_funcnames 0 : { *(.debug_funcnames) }
.debug_typenames 0 : { *(.debug_typenames) }
.debug_varnames  0 : { *(.debug_varnames) }
/* These must appear regardless of  .  */
}
```

Linker version is very old too (yeah I know...):

```
GNU ld 2.9.1
Copyright 1997 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: The answer is likely to be found in your system's linker scripts.  Link with `gcc -v -Wl,--verbose` and you'll get a dump of it.

Comment: AFAIK the `.comment` section isn't used by any tools in particular; it's just there for the programmer to inspect manually (with `objdump` or `readelf`) if they need to know what compiler version was used.

Comment: I thought that too, but in that case why this weird address? it should be zero.

Comment: Yes, I don't know the reason for the address either, but I suspect that it's determined by the linker script, directly or indirectly.

Comment: added linker script. no trace of `.comment`. AFAIR if there's a section without mapping the linker chooses to put whatever it chooses (unless we discard it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why is there a non-zero address for the comment section

Most likely there is a bug in the linker, and it puts uninitialized data there (the data doesn't matter, but reproducible builds *are* a design goal, and so inability to achieve a reproducible build *is* a bug).

You didn't say which linker (and which version) you used.

Using `GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.34` or `GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Debian 2.34) 1.16`, I consistently get `00000000` for `.comment` section's `Addr`.

Comment: I'm using a linker that your avatar may have used too. Your answer makes sense. I'm going to strip this section from the final executable